# Approximating volume using differentials

Tags: calculus

A closed box with dimension $10$ cm, $8$ cm, $6$ cm,  is made of $2$ mm thick plywood. Approximate the volume of material used in making the box.

We have $V=xyz$

We can find what the approximate change in volume is when we change each dimension by 2 mm:

The differential is:

$dV=yz dz+xz dy+ xy dz \approx yz\Delta{z}+xz \Delta{y}+xy \Delta{z}$

Evaluating this at $(10,8,6)$ and $\Delta{x},\Delta{y}, \Delta{z}=(-.2)$ We get $|dV|\approx 37.6 \ cm^3$.

The answer in the book is given as $dV \approx 75 \ cm^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only widened one wall on each side.

Comment: @ Karolis Juodelè Your justification is not convincing. If the length of each dimension  is changed, every side and the volume will be changed in a right way.

Comment: @calculus, if a wall of 2 mm is added, each dimension changes by 4 mm, given two opposing walls. As the OP only changed the dimensions by 2 mm, I assumed that he ignored the second wall. Hence my answer.

Comment: @ Karolis Juodelè What is a wall of 2mm ? The unit should be $mm^2$ I really don't understand your point.

Comment: @calculus, 2 mm is thickness. For some reason I think of this as adding walls rather than removing them. There is no difference though, given $\approx$.

Comment: Juodelè Now I get your point. With your interpretation of the exercise I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution refers to the assumption, that the length of each dimension can be enlarged or reducded by 2mm.

So $|\Delta x|+|-\Delta x|=|\Delta y|+|-\Delta y|=|\Delta z|+|-\Delta z|=|0.2|+|-0.2|=0.4$

So the question is, what the approximate change in volume is when we change each dimension, **postitive or negative**, by 2 mm ?

greetings,

calculus